# Identify this plant or shrub

Tags: identification

I have had this plant for the past 2 years. Can any one tell me the name of the plant.[image]

Comment: Could you add some more information: where did you find such plant? Do you think it is a wild plant?

Comment: I think this is a wild plant. It started from the bird droping. region from india

Comment: Could you add the region you see that plant? Without knowing the region, I think nobody will risk an answer.

Comment: Is it woody? I can't tell whether the stuff behind the leaves is part of the same plant.